# SQLiteDatabase DROP TABLE IF EXISTS not working

Tags: android, database, sqlite

**Situation**
I need to delete all entries of a specific Table in the database so i figured i would just drop it.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LogEntry
```

I tried running the sql using `SQLiteDatabase#execSql(String)` and `SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(String, String[])`. I start a transaction before execution it and end it after executing it using `SQLiteDatabase#beginTransaction()` and `SQLiteDatabase#endTransaction()`.

**Problem**
In both cases the SQL executed without throwing an Exception but the table still exists. I ran a SELECT Statement right after the drop to see if it worked and it had the same results as before the drop.

Comment: Why not just `delete from LogEntry`. Then you don't need to recreate it

Comment: @juergend That would be a possible workaround, but i dont need the table once its empty. Im mostly interested in the reason why the drop statement executes but doesn't have any effect.

Comment: `beginTransaction()` has to be called BEFORE executing your SQL commands. `rawQuery()` is only used to run **queries**, not **commands**. It's actually `execSql()`, not `executeSql()`

Comment: Where exactly do you have the transaction? Note the blockquote in @MikeT's answer talking about nested transactions - `SQLiteOpenHelper` lifecycle callbacks are already run inside a transaction.

Comment: @Basti You have change your database version ?

Comment: @KlingKlang Shouldn't matter then wether the transaction is open or not when the sql executes. Still doesn't explain why it doesn't have any effect. And my bad, typo. I corrected it.

Comment: It actually **does** matter. Because that marks the starting point of the transaction recording. If you do something **outside** the transaction, that's **not recorded** at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, assuimg #'s are **.**'s, the reason is that you have omitted the **setTransactionSuccessful**, without this **endTransaction** will rollback (undo everything done in the transaction).

As per :-

> Transactions can be nested. When the outer transaction is ended all of
>   the work done in that transaction and all of the nested transactions
>   will be committed or rolled back. **The changes will be rolled back if
>   any transaction is ended without being marked as clean (by calling
>   setTransactionSuccessful)**. Otherwise they will be committed.

[beginTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#beginTransaction())